# VBA - Excel - Save As and delete original workbook

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

From a Personal.xlsb file, I want VBA to save the current active workbook as a user-definable name in the same directory and delete the original workbook.

Below is my code. It has two problems. One, it saves the workbook in My Documents folder for some reason. The active workbook is not in My Documents. It's in a folder in a completely different drive. Two, it throws a "File not found" error.

```
Sub RenameFile()
Dim thisWb As Workbook
Set thisWb = ActiveWorkbook
MyOldName = ActiveWorkbook.Name
MyNewName = InputBox("What do you want to rename the file as?", "Rename", ActiveWorkbook.Name)

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=thisWb.Path & MyNewName
Kill MyOldName
End Sub
```

Comment: In order to delete the original file, you need to assign the `MyOldName` variable to `ActiveWorkbook.FullName` instead of just .Name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to include a `\` after path and before filename.

```
Sub RenameFile()
Dim thisWb As Workbook
Set thisWb = ActiveWorkbook
MyOldName = ActiveWorkbook.FullName
MyNewName = InputBox("What do you want to rename the file as?", "Rename", ActiveWorkbook.Name)

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=thisWb.Path & "\" & MyNewName
Kill MyOldName
End Sub
```

Edit: Updated answer to include fix from comment.

Comment: It is saving the new file in the current directory with this, but I'm still getting the "File not found" error. It doesn't delete the original file.

Comment: Try changing `MyOldName = ActiveWorkbook.Name` to `MyOldName = ActiveWorkbook.FullName`

Answer (score 0):

So I have some code that I use to auto save files (to a directory specified in the code) and then deletes a particular file type out of said folder. (I use it to save a .xlsx and delete .csv)

```
'Saves file to specified location
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs filename:="C:\Desktop\Testing\Testing File " _
    & Format(Now() - 1, "DD.MM.YY") & ".xlsx" _
    , FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False

    On Error Resume Next
    Kill "C:\Desktop\Testing*.csv*"
    On Error GoTo 0
```

This is the code that I used that is within a longer VBA module, but you could incorporate this into existing VBA code

Take note that that currently saves the file as Testing with the day before the current system date in the name, such as "Testing 30.10.16"

Comment: The active workbook could be in many different directories and therefore need to be saved in many different directories, so I can't specify directories in the code.

Comment: @Robby Oh ok, in that case I misinterpreted your question. I'll leave the answer here just incase in benefits someone else with a similar issue.